# Remove custom attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this code with custom attribute `header` :

```
<div id="foo" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12"
directives="directives"
header="{ name: 'Landing Page' }" style="border-width:5px; border-style:dashed;"></div>
```

When I execute this code, it will remove the dashed border but not the `Landing Page` text.

```
    var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#foo' ) );
    myEl.removeAttr('style');
    myEl.removeAttr('header');
```

Why don't the text disappear and how can I remove custom attribute? Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: It does - see this working fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/nj62zvad/ Which angularJS version are you using?

Comment: Most likely because it is a directive which has been already compiled when you execute this code. [Don't mix Angular with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).

Comment: I use angular 1.5.3

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a **directive** instead because i don't think you can remove an attribute that has not been defined for that specific tag. If you use a directive you may create a custom attribute.